# Where are sql databases saved on hard drive?

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

I have a hard drive that will not boot that has wamp server installed on it.  I can still access the hard drive files(barely), but need to find out how to transfer the MySQL databases to a new computer.  Anyone know where these are saved?

Comment: I copied this file over to the new install, and it copies the database, but not the table data within....?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find the data from your MySQL database on your harddrive, follow these steps:

1. Locate the `my.ini` file in your MySQL installation directory.
2. Find the line that states `datadir`.

   For example:

   ```
   datadir="C:/Documents and Settings/All Users/Application Data/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.1/Data/"
   ```
3. This directory contains the data you are looking for.

Comment: I got the databases to import, but the data within(column/row information and data) did not